# Xamarin forms SQLiteNetExtensions Data Binding

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to display a list of ingredient objects within a recipe page.

I have 2 tables Ingredients

```
 public class Ingredients
{
    // primary key
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int IngredientsId { get; set; }

    // specify the foreign key
    [ForeignKey(typeof(Recipe))]
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }

    // many to one relationship with recipe
    [ManyToOne]
    public Recipe Recipe { get; set; }

    // other attributes
    public string IngredientsName { get; set; }
    public double Ammount { get; set; }
    public string Units { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return IngredientsName + "      " + Ammount + Units;
    }
}
```

and recipe

```
    public class Recipe
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int RecipeID { get; set; }
    public string RecipeName { get; set; }
    public string VideoURL { get; set; }
    public string PrepTime { get; set; }
    public string CookTime { get; set; }
    public int Serves { get; set; }
    public string MealType { get; set; }
    public string Equipment { get; set; }
    public string Method { get; set; }

    // one to many relationship with ingredients 
    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public List<Ingredients> Ingredients { get; set; }

}
```

they both hold each other in 2 way relationship, I know this through debugging. I am now trying to use databinding to show a recipe page with all the ingredients in a ListView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:video="clr-namespace:SQLiteListView.FormsVideoLibrary"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SQLiteListView.Models"
             x:Class="SQLiteListView.Views.ItemPage"
             Title="{Binding RecipeName}">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding RecipeName}"
                       FontSize="50"/>
                <video:VideoPlayer HeightRequest="320" WidthRequest="220">
                    <video:VideoPlayer.Source>
                        <video:ResourceVideoSource>
                            <video:ResourceVideoSource.Path>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="Videos/iOSApiVideo.mp4" />
                                    <On Platform="Android" Value="ScrambledEggs.mp4" />
                                    <On Platform="UWP" Value="Videos/UWPApiVideo.mp4" />
                                </OnPlatform>
                            </video:ResourceVideoSource.Path>
                        </video:ResourceVideoSource>
                    </video:VideoPlayer.Source>
                </video:VideoPlayer>

                <Label 
                    Margin="10"
                    Text="Meal Type"
                    FontSize="Large" 
                    FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding MealType}"
                       Margin="10"
                       FontSize="Medium"/>

                <Label Margin="10"
                       Text="Serves" 
                       FontSize="Large" 
                       FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Serves}" 
                       Margin="10"
                       FontSize="Medium"/>

                <Label Margin="10"
                       Text="Preperation Time" 
                       FontSize="Large" 
                       FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding PrepTime}" 
                       Margin="10"
                       FontSize="Medium"/>

                <Label Margin="10"
                       Text="Cooking Time" 
                       FontSize="Large" 
                       FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding CookTime}"  
                       Margin="10"
                       FontSize="Medium"/>

                <Label Margin="10"
                       Text="Equipment" 
                       FontSize="Large"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Equipment}" 
                       Margin="10"
                       FontSize="Medium"/>

                <Label Margin="10"
                       Text="Ingredients" 
                       FontSize="Large" 
                       FontAttributes="Bold"/>

                <ListView x:Name="IngredientsListView" ItemsSource ="Ingredients">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding IngredientName }"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Ammount}"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Units}"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>

                <Label Margin="10"
                       Text="Method" 
                       FontSize="Large" 
                       FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Method}"  
                       Margin="10"
                       FontSize="Medium"/>

            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I have tried to get the ingredients from an enumarator, but I am unable to just get the ingredients attached to the recipe. I have tried to just add Recipe.Ingredients as an ItemSource to the ListView but that doesn't seem to work either.

Can Anyone Help?

Comment: Specify what doesn't show and what's showing in your `ScrollView`. Also, do `Ingredients` have more than 1 element ?

Comment: Also I would put all your `Ingredients` into a `ObservableListView` and then bind that new instance to the `ItemsSource`

Comment: Hi Greggz, thanks for your reply. Everything shows in the ScrollView apart from the Ingredients. There is a different number of ingredients in each recipe, each Ingriedient displayed should have the name amount and units in a single line.

Comment: I have tried to put all ingredients into an ObservableCollection and bind from there and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please give the StackLayout a `HeigthRequested`. Also try feeding the Listview another set of items, to make sure the problem doesn't come from the ingredients. Modify the viewcells if u must